# Attempting to get Drive events from Google Reports API returns no results

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the documentation for "[Retrieve Google Drive events for a domain](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive#retrieve_drive_name_events_for_a_domain)" and using the [Google PHP Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to return events that users on my domain have made on Google Drive. I'm able to get this to work with other APIs using the client library and am not seeing any errors related to authentication. When I make this one call, I get an empty document.

I know there are events on our domain as we're pretty active using Google Docs / Drive.

After authenticated and setting up the client with at least the following permissions:

```
$this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Reports::ADMIN_REPORTS_AUDIT_READONLY);
$this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Reports::ADMIN_REPORTS_USAGE_READONLY);
```

I make my call like so:

```
$reports = new Google_Service_Reports($this->client);
$events = $reports->activities->listActivities('all','drive')->getItems();
```

$events is returning an empty array.

Am I mistaken as to the function of this request or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, this report will only work if your domain is signed up for Google Apps Unlimited. Can you confirm that you are?

Comment: I'm working off a Google Apps for Non Profits account, which I guess may not necessarily be eligible.